Their is an issue with the database deploy pipeline
Their is an issue with the database deploy pipeline. When someone pushes to the repo it auto builds in jenkins which is fine. Problem is that it always fails. The auto build shouldnt really be doing anything at all so no reason for it to be failing.  I think there is some type of null point exception value error but I am not sure how to know what needs to be fixed to ensure that it doesn't fail.
line 29 database deploy pipeline

Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.
